# Showing binary PDF in browser Javascript

Tags: javascript, express, pdf, blob

I have a MSSQL Server Database with files stored as a column `Content` of type `VARBINARY(MAX)` in a SQL table.

I developed a backend Node.js server with Express.js to access the database. In this backend I have a route called `/api/file/:id_file` which takes the content of the file with `id_file`

```
async getFile(req,res){
    const {id_file} = req.query
    const file= await db.Files.findOne({
        where:{
            'Id': id_file,
        }
        
    })
    res.contentType('application/pdf')
    res.send(file.Content)
}
```

Then in frontend using Javascript, I have an iframe

```
<iframe id="view" src="" style='height: 500px; width: 1000px;' />
```

And I use an ajax request to get the file. When I have the response, I just convert it to blob and set the src attribute of iframe element with the base64 encoding of the blob

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = () => {
  const b64 = reader.result.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, "");
  $('#view').attr('src','data:application/pdf;base64,'+ b64);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([resp.data], { type: "application/pdf" }));
```

When I try to request a file and show, I see a blank PDF, nothing is shown.

Am I missing any step to convert the content of the file to base64?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a filereader since you're not reading a file from the filesystem or user input; you already have the file pulled down from the API. If your binary pdf data is in `resp.data` then you just need to use [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa)

> creates a Base64-encoded ASCII string from a binary string

```
$('#view').attr('src','data:application/pdf;base64,'+ btoa(resp.data));
```

Comment: Thanks, but it throws an error: "InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range."

Comment: interesting. try this instead: `btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(resp.data)))`

Comment: error disappears but now I have the same problem I describe in Question, the pdf shows as blank document

Comment: @E.Williams I am facing the same issue, have you found the solution to this?

Comment: @RikkMor Nop. I supposed there was some incompatibility with encoding from sql server and base64. I decided just to download the pdf to local storage so the user can use his own pdf viewer